# Showing some set is not algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification

I want to solve the Exercise 1.13 (c) in Fulton's *Algebraic Curves* Book:

> Show that the set $\{(\cos t,\sin t,t)\in\mathbb{A}^3(\mathbb R)\mid t\in\mathbb R\}$ is not an algebraic set.

I have a solution. Can you check if it is accurate? Thanks in advance. My solution is the following:
 
Suppose if possible the given set is algebraic. The line: $(y=0, x=1)$ intersects the given set (name as ) $V$ infinite times.
Now $V=\cap V(F)$ where $F$ is a polynomial in $k[x,y,z]$. If $\forall F$, $V(F)$ contains all the points in the line: $(y=0, x=1)$ then $V$ will also contain all the points in the above mentioned line which is not true.
 So, $V\subset V(F)$, where $F$ is a polynomial whose zero set does not include all the points in the above mentioned line(may contain some point).We have chosen $F$ such a way that $F(1,0,z)$ cannot be a zero polynomial. So, $F(1,0,z)$ has atmost finite number of roots.But $V\subset V(F)$, so V intersects the above mentioned line  finite time, which is a contradiction

Comment: Not that it's a seal of quality, but this is what I would do.